# How to set a SearchView's input type to numeric

Tags: android, android-view, android-actionbar

I currently have a `SearchView` in my app's `ActionBar` (of which I am populating from an XML layout file) and I am trying to force it to only take numeric input. I've tried setting the `android:inputType="number"` attribute in XML, but it has no effect.

Does anyone know the source of this problem?

The XML menu resource:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search_holo_light"
        android:inputType="number" />       
</menu>
```

Comment: See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I know to consult the Android documentation before asking questions on StackOverflow :P

Comment: Further, the documentation seems suggests that there shouldn't be any problem with this method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're setting it in a compatibility library fragment, you need to use [`SearchViewCompat.setInputType(View searchView, int inputType)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompat.html#setInputType%28android.view.View,%20int%29):

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchable, menu);
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    if (searchMenuItem != null) {
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        if (searchView != null) {
            SearchViewCompat.setInputType(searchView, InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_POSTAL_ADDRESS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SearchViewCompat.setInputType()` is deprecated. It's been changed that you can directly access to inputType. 

Kotlin
`searchView.setInputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`

Comment: Should be `searchView?.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`

Answer (score 14):

setInputType on a searchView was introduced in API  14. To set it to number try :

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: This also works with the AppCompat-v7 android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.

Comment: searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Answer (score 3):

When using `SearchView` from `android.support.v7.widget` you can use:

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer, but keep in mind that the usefulness of input type filters can be contingent on the IME you're using; some keyboards don't readily obey these input types... I learned that the hard way. :(

With that in mind, have you tried using other input types to see if they'll stick?  If they do stick, it's likely an IME issue.  If they don't, it's likely an issue with the way in which you're trying to enforce the input type.

Now, for a shot at an answer:

You might try, in onCreateOptionsMenu, doing a lookup by ID of that menu item, casting to a SearchView, and setting the input type in code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.default_menu, menu);

    if (MyApplication.SUPPORTS_HONEYCOMB) { // quick check for API level
        // If we have the honeycomb API, set up the search view
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);

        SearchView search = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        // your code here.  something like:
        search.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL);

        // you also likely want to set up your search listener here.

    }

    // I'm using ActionBarCompat, in which case
    // calling super after populating the menu is necessary here to ensure that the
    // action bar helpers have a chance to handle this event.
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks for the help. I've tried a couple others (i.e. `android:inputType="phone"`), but those had no effect. Further, it looks like [setInputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html#setInputType(int)) was introduced in API 14, which I haven't begun supporting yet. GRRR

Comment: The obvious solution would be to just make a custom `EditText` but there has to be a way to do this w/o customization...

Comment: It occurs to me that if the java code to support the input type on the SearchView doesn't exist until API14 that the same is probably true of the inputType XML attribute on that object.  Maybe build your app for API14 with the inputType attribute in the SearchView, and see if it takes effect?  That would probably indicate whether or not this is accurate.

Comment: ~1 year later, testing this on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.2.1 and it works! Not sure if it works on pre ICS devices yet... I'll report back when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin users

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    val searchMenuItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
    val searchView = searchMenuItem?.actionView as SearchView
    searchView.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER
    return true
}
```