# Can we limit the number of character in edittext of SearchView in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any api to set the limit no. of characters in SearchView ?

Comment: `Edittext`'s XML attribute `android:maxLength=15` will allow only 15 character. Is this only you need?

Comment: This may not work... `SearchView` doesn't extend `EditText`. I know that `inputType` doesn't work on `SearchView` for some reason either.

Comment: @AlexLockwood May i know what's the `SearchView` Is that like `AutocomplteTextView`

Comment: No, `AutoCompleteTextView` extends `EditText`; `SearchView` extends `LinearLayout`. The backend for `SearchView` is much more complex. Although it looks almost exactly like an `EditText`, it is much more complicated and is meant to be used with a search interface.

Comment: This might be a bit 'hackey' (is that a word?) but could you not put an edit text overtop and use textChangedWatcher to update the searchView?  I know it's wouldn't be ideal but would it work?  Sometimes the only way is with a bigger hammer.

Comment: @Alex Lockwood  Do u know how to do this stuff.

Comment: I asked a similar question [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543620/how-to-set-a-searchviews-input-type-to-numeric) and never got an answer. This question sounds similar... so I'm not so sure if there's an easy way to do it. :/

Answer (score 13):

I am using following code snippet:

```
TextView et = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
```

Answer (score 7):

***Use this code it will do search only if length is less or equal to 5.You can make it change accordingly like returning true from onQueryTextChange() when text>5.***

```
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();     
          searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mActivity.getSearchComponentName()));
          searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
          searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
          searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String arg0) {
                if(arg0.length()>5){
                    System.out.println("Text character is more than 5");
                    searchView.setQuery(arg0.substring(0,5), false);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

```
EditText et = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
            .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter({max_text_length}) });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code snippet in case R.id.search_src_text unresolved:

```
val searchEdt = searchView.findViewById<EditText>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
searchEdt.filters = arrayOf(InputFilter.LengthFilter(10))
```

Answer (score -5):

In XML layout try this..

```
 android:maxLength="20" //20 is number of characters.
```

Comment: Have you seen this [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914539/can-we-limit-the-number-of-character-in-edittext-of-searchview-in-android#comment14233570_10914539)

Comment: In SearchView  there is nothing to set character length.

Comment: Search view does not have "maxLength"