# How do we add maxlength in SearchView?

Tags: android, searchview

Is there a method to give max length to `SearchView`?

Saw a few questions but did not get a satisfying answer.

Comment: Post something what you have tried?

Comment: This may help find "himb2001" answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914539/can-we-limit-the-number-of-character-in-edittext-of-searchview-in-android/16033389

Comment: did not get any good ans so couldn't try anything, tryied thios :http://stackoverflow.com/a/16033389/5327912 but it only stops search after a text limit, but i dont want the use to enter after a certain limit , like we do in maxlength for edittext

Comment: @Ram already saw that question, and that does not solve the probelm

Comment: @duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914539/can-we-limit-the-number-of-character-in-edittext-of-searchview-in-android