# Setting maxLength for SearchView

Tags: android, material-design

Is it possible to limit `SearchView` input text length?
I have added `android:maxLength="10"` in `Menu Item` declaration but has no effect.

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:maxLength="10"/>
```

Comment: did you [try this link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914539/can-we-limit-the-number-of-character-in-edittext-of-searchview-in-android/16033389)

Comment: This a possible duplicate of the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25457111/2984447 - that has a working solution too:) from [Alexander Zhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653775/alexander-zhak).
Answer marked correct in the this post throws a null pointer exception.
I wished to only add comment here, but do not have the privileges yet! Apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can achieved this by using SO one answer in the link suggested by `Jyoti JK`:

```
TextView et = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10)});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this will help you:

```
EditText et = (EditText)searchView.findViewById(searchView.getContext().getResources()
        .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null));
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter({10}) });
```

Comment: for me :searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text) and variants didn't work, only your solution work for find edittext after a lot of googling

Comment: Use of getIdentifier is discouraged because resource reflection makes it harder to perform build optimizations and compile-time verification of code