# Allow only some desired character to input in SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-view, searchview

I am using `SearchView` as item as follow:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/my_search_view"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24px"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:digits="0123456789 qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

But android:digits not working here.
How i can achieve it in searchview

Comment: this may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543620/how-to-set-a-searchviews-input-type-to-numeric

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Java code.

For **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView**:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

For **android.widget.SearchView**:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) searchView.findViewById(android.R.id.search_src_text);
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setKeyListener(android.text.method.KeyListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: @SoniKumar, are you using `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`?

Comment: No i am using searchview as item in toolbar as above xml file

Comment: Change `android.widget.SearchView` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` in your `<item>`.

Comment: It will effect my other code so i can not change it

Answer (score -1):

Allow only certain characters in edittext

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "
```

lower case & upper case with allowing space

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));
```

lower case with allowing space

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));
```

upper case with allowing space

```
yourEditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "));
```

Answer (score -1):

Provide your condition to return the desired character

```
private void addFilterToUserName()
    {

        sign_up_display_name_et.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if(src.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return src;
                        }
                        if(src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z 0-9]+")){
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```